# Android Studio 2.2.2 Ошибка "No CPU/ABI system image available for this target"

Tags: android-studio

Создаю программу впервые. При помощи AVD manager хочу создать AVD но поле CPU/ABI остаётся пустым, не высвечивается кнопка ОК и пишет:

> No CPU/ABI system image available for this target

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно скачать системный образ Android. Делается это, насколько я помню, в SDK Manager'e.

Comment: если это комментарий, отправьте тревогу модераторам, чтобы перенесли ответ в комментарий. если это решение, то все хорошо(только лишний текст удалите).

Comment: На мой взгляд, это вполне ответ. Что тут ещё можно добавить-то, скриншот кнопки "Download"?

Comment: Впрочем, можно добавить пару слов про CPU/ABI system image, что это такое и почему нужно качать отдельно. И если нужно будет выбрать из нескольких — то как выбрать.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о eclipse, то нужно зайти Window-> Android SDK manager и установить для нужних платформ "ARM EABI v7a System Image". Тут есть то, что Вам нужно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device.

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос - "для нужних платформ "ARM EABI v7a System Image"" - чем это поможет?